# Best way to attach to process (IIS)

Tags: visual-studio

in my VS2012 I need around 10 seconds to attach the VS to the iisexpress.exe service and debug something...

That is way to much, is there a shorter way (e.g. macro / shortcut) to do it?

At the moment I must:
Tool -> Attach to Process -> Wait for Process window -> find iisexpress service (scroll down) -> click the line -> click attach -> Wait

Comment: Couldn't you use the built-in web server of VS2012 that may be faster?

Comment: this is an outright off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about]**. Why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @gnat: Possibly because it isn't suited to SO. There is no code involved and no particular language. This question may not be about programming concepts, but it certainly is about programming and meets the "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." requirement. If anywhere, it should probably be on superuser? But I certainly wouldn't have picked that as my first choice to ask an IDE related question.

Comment: @gnat: ah ok, thanks. It just wouldn't have entered my mind as the site to ask IDE related questions, but if it is explicitly on topic there, I'd better try to rewire my brain :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2012 doesn't support Macros the way that previous versions did, but there are still some ways to streamline the process:

- Keyboard shortcuts.

  1. Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> shortcut to get into the Process window.
  2. Click <kbd>i</kbd> to scroll automatically to the processes starting with *i*, repeating the click to cycle through all the *i* processes.
  3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to attach to the currently highlighted process.

With some practice, attaching to a process like this could take 1-2 seconds at most, bound mostly by the time it takes for the Process Window to load.

- 3rd Party Tools.

There are probably others, but one tool I know that can help you is [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/) (disclaimer: I work for the company that owns this product), a debugging helper tool that, among its features has [Quick Attach](http://o.oz-code.com/features#quickAttach), a feature which automatically assigns hotkeys (like <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>, etc) to commonly attached processes. If iisexpress is your main process, it will be assigned that hotkey, and you can attach to it quickly.

Comment: Nice tool but 100Dollar for a simple quickattach feature is a bit too much here ;) But nice tool!

Comment: I favour Reattach http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cccc206-b9de-42ef-8f5a-160ad0f017ae - it's awesome.

Comment: Wow nice razethestray - do this as answer pls, so i can upvote and accept :)